# How to make WP admin recognize a newly created child theme?

Tags: theme-development

I am having a problem that's very similar to the one described [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/yet-another-child-theme-problem-cant-activate-child-theme), except that the solution that worked for him (text encoding) didn't work for me.

I even tried applying `unix2dos -o style.css` from the command line (which definitely changed the file from LF to CRLF, as I could see that the file increased slightly in size), but that didn't help.

I also tried clicking the button `Search Installed Themes` but that didn't help either.

What are the requirements for making a child theme appear in the admin's list of Available Themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem - and fixed it!

It turns out that LF vs. CRLF is not an issue at all on a LAMP based webhost.

The problem in my particular case was that I copied the original theme's `style.css` **verbatim**, and it was missing a very critical line in the comment section:

```
Template: twentyeleven
```

Once I fixed that everything started working as expected.

Note: Template should point at the parent's directory, not the child's one.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed